# Exterior lights turn off

Tags: electrical, lights

A few weeks ago, my lights started turning off. I'd come back later and they would work fine.

I thought it was the lighting column stalk, so I put in a temporary switch taking over from the stalk in providing an earth. However, they continued switching off.

Then, I happened to open the bonnet (at the front) and the headlights switched on (I'd left the light stalk in the on position).  All the lights worked fine but when I closed the bonnet, the headlights' relay clicked the lights off again; I heard the distinctive click.

The under bonnet light switch seems to be the culprit as I the lights went off when I depressed the switch nipple, simulating a closed bonnet.

I'm not that good at automotive electronics and can't understand how a switch can cause the lighting relay to switch off.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a ground problem, not a switch problem.  The under-bonnet light and its switch are not the culprits, but a clue.

Not having a wiring diagram for your vehicle in front of me, I can't tell you anything about the wiring layout.  However, it appears that the under-bonnet light is providing a ground path for the headlight relay in lieu of its proper ground path.  When you press the under-bonnet switch plunger (not "nipple"), you are opening this ground path and the relay goes off.  The same thing should happen if you remove the under-bonnet bonnet bulb itself.

What you need to do is find the headlight relay and trace its ground path or look at a wiring diagram to determine the ground path, then correct any broken/intermittent connectors/wires/attachments.  It could be as simple as tightening a ground lug, or as difficult as re-wiring the relay.

Comment: Hi Scrappy, Thanks for your help, v useful. I have got a wring diagram that I can e-mail to you. I can't see a way of attaching it to this message, unless you know how? Otherwise can I e-mail to you?

Comment: Glad to be of help, Chris.  It would be helpful to state the year/make/model/options (and any modifications relevant to wiring) of your vehicle, then we can see if the wiring diagram is already out there on the internet.  I would be normally be OK with having you email it to me, but given that there are is no private messaging function here, I don't want to put my email out for all to see.

Comment: Hi Scrappy, I understand about not giving out e-mail address. The car is a European spec 1973 Ferrari Dino 246 GTS. No electric windows, emission controls or air con. Here's a link to the wiring diagram:

Comment: Sorry here's link: http://www.unevoiture.com/manuals/doc/d389-owners-manual-dino-246-gt-1973-us/read?page=26          Do you need a legend?

Comment: Sorry forgot to say that I'm not using electronic ignition - just normal coil and mechanical points

Comment: Chris, I clicked to page 25 and got the legend. :)

It looks as if the under-bonnet light is a red herring, whether it's the front or rear (#9 and #43).  They are powered along with the side marker and license plate circuit.

I think you're going to have to do some old-fashioned circuit tracing with a multi-meter.  You're going to have to check continuity (end-to-end) and shorts (between each end and ground) for each wire while the components are disconnected.

Comment: Scrappy, I checked the bulb holder under the bonnet and the bulb was missing. I put one in and, joyousness, the main lights worked with the bonnet down. How does that work? Does something (relay, light swith?) see the earth through the bonnet switch somehow even when its open?
Once agin, much appreciated, you're a star!
Best Chris

Comment: Chris, glad you got it fixed!

It might be that one of the leads was shorting because the bulb was not there to hold it in place.  If you were to put something non-conductive there (such as a piece of wood dowel that matches the bulb shape), I wonder if the behavior would be the same.

Comment: I'll try that and report back. Best Chris

Answer (score 0):

If the car has an automatic light option like nearly all cars do it really sounds like you're gonna have to replace what they call a headlight switch for some reason in parts stores. It looks like a little receptacle box that a wiring harness plugs directly up to. For some reason that part can effect every light on the car. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Trigga, Thanks for your response. The car is a 1973 model so hasn't got the automatic light option - I'm assuming you mean the option you get on modern cars that automatically switches the lights on when it starts getting dark?

Comment: Yes. And that same little terminal can also prevent your taillights from coming on even when using the switch manually.

Comment: Italian auto electrics!! Why did they make things complicated back in the '70s (-;